# Discrete Proportion data -GLMM, regresion beta or multinominal logistic distribution

Tags: mixed-model, biostatistics, proportion, glmm

I have an experiment that have nine treatments consisting of three strains with three different levels of application. Each treatment involves 20 plants, and measurements were taken at three-time points over 10-day intervals, resulting in repeated measures data.

My dataset includes the proportion of endophytism in leaves, calculated by counting the pieces of leaves where the inoculated fungus was found relative to the total pieces of leaves in the Petri dish. The proportion values range from 0 to 1, excluding both endpoints.

I'm considering one modeling approach using the glmmTMB function in R, but I'm uncertain about the appropriate family to use and whether to include leaf size as a random effect in the Model 1. Here is my proposed model:

```r
M1 <- glmmTMB(Endophytism ~ Treatment * Strain * Days + (1+Days|Plant), 
              family=??, data = Datos_OBJT2)
```

For me is important interactions between treatment, strain, and days. And "days" now is treated as a factor.

See in comments a possible solution using a simple binomial regression.

`m3 <- glmer(cbind(Total_Infected, Total_No_Infected) ~ Treatment * Strain * Days + (1|Plant),                        family = binomial, data = Datos_OBJT2)`

I would appreciate any help or recommendations on which analysis approach would be the best for my data.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is there some reason why you can't use a simple binomial (e.g., logistic) regression? That should work OK if you have counts for the numbers of infected and non-infected leaf pieces (a 2- column outcome of yes/no counts per Petri dish). But perhaps I'm missing something here in the details of your experiments.

Comment: I´m using a binomial regression:

`m3 <- glmer(cbind(Total_Infected, Total_No_Infected) ~ Treatment * Strain * Days + (1|Plant), 
                      family = binomial, data = Datos_OBJT2)`

I'm trying to simulate a repeated measures model, but as I understand, a binomial logistic model requires independence of the data. I'm looking for an alternative or to know if what I'm doing is correct when I add a random effect to the model because my data is repeated measures in time.

Comment: Is the first measurement for each plant before or after `Treatment` is applied? How is the `Days` variable coded (factor or numeric)? How many observations are there?

Comment: All measurements are after applying the treatment.
Time is coded as a numeric variable.
In total there are 3 measurements every 10 days, for each treatment. 
Each treatment has 20 plants in total.

Comment: To make things easier for new visitors to this page, please edit your question to include the important extra information that you have provided in your comments. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: I've modified the question and I include the potential solutions. Thank you for your assistance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a simple yes/no for infection status of each leaf piece, this should be handled OK by a binomial (e.g., logistic) regression, with the two-column outcome variable that you show in a comment. Incorporating `Plant` as a random  effect will take the lack of independence of results within individual plants into account.

Treating `Days` as numeric might get you into trouble. Numeric coding means that you are assuming a linear association between `Days` and the outcome (log-odds of a leaf piece being infected if you use logistic regression). That's probably unrealistic. With only 3 values possible for `Days` it's simplest to treat it as a 3-level categorical predictor, allowing each day to have its own association with outcome.

Whether and how to adjust for `Leaf_size` depends on your experimental setup and your understanding of the subject matter. If I understand the experimental setup correctly, it seems that a smaller leaf will tend to have fewer pieces placed into the Petri dish; that provides one type of correction (higher variance in proportion estimates with fewer leaf pieces).

If you think that the *probability* of a leaf piece being infected depends on `Leaf_size`, other things being equal, then you should use it as a predictor. As `Leaf_size` is a continuous predictor, you should consider flexible fitting (e.g., a regression spline) so that you don't implicitly make an assumption of a linear association with outcome.

Finally, your original question used only additive terms for the predictors, but the model in a comment includes interactions among all fixed-effect predictors. I suspect that the interactions will be important, but that would depend on your understanding of the subject matter.